# Carriage return in unix scripting

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tired this but the line carriage doesn't work properly.
I even tried \r\n without luck.

```
sudo sed -i "s/webmaster@localhost/info@domain.com\rServerName domain.com \rServerAlias www.domain.com/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain
```

I get this weird character there between:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin info@domain.com ^MServerName domain.com ^MServerAlias www.domain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing?

Many Thanks,

Comment: @Mat: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unix text file line ending char is `\n`, ASCII 0x0A (new line/line feed). `\r` 0xOD is a carriage return.

Replace `\r` by `\n` in your sed expression and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

One way with `sed` (GNU version):

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## Match line with string 'serveradmin' ignoring case.
/serveradmin/I {
    ## Append text after this line.
    a\  
## Literal text to append until a line not ending with '\'
\tServerName domain.com\
\tServerAlias www.domain.com
}
```

Run the script:

```
sed -f script.sed infile
```

And result:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        ServerName domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        ServerAlias www.domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                           

        DocumentRoot /var/www/                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        <Directory />                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                Options FollowSymLinks                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                AllowOverride None                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
</VirtualHost>
```